# Are questions related to IPFS on topic at Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope

Are questions related to [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) on-topic at Stack Overflow?

My actual question is:

> IPFS allows data persistence in face of garbage collection via pinning. However what happens when the physical infrastructure hosting node/s that pinned the data go down? Does the data still persist? Specifically, if the data had only been pinned on a single node that suddenly experienced a failure, would the data be lost? Is it safe to say that data persistence on IPFS isn't tolerant to node failure unless said data has reached sufficient pinning by multiple nodes? What would be the threshold for such sufficiency?

Comment: It depends. It would be helpful if you added a sample of the kind of questions you would like to ask.

Comment: @cigien I added my actual q. Should I post?

Comment: Thanks for adding an example question. No, you should definitely wait a bit for feedback from the community before deciding whether to post your question on the main site.

Comment: Regardless whether IPFS questions were on-topic or not, that question is certainly not. It seems to match at least the *needs more focus* and *opinion based* close reasons. Might *need details or clarity* to make it a [practical, answerable problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The official docs have a chapter called "persistence" (exactly the area of your questioning) and that chapter contains a paragraph "pinning services" which basically directly and indirectly answers your questions. Offsite pinning services exist with which you can create a harder guarantee that your data is not lost by using them as a backup. https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/persistence/#pinning-services . Read: yes backups are still a necessity with this system, standard backup wisdom applies.

Comment: I found that in under a minute... that usually means you're not asking a question that is researched well enough. OR you should mention the missing information in your question and why it doesn't apply.

Comment: @Gimby thanks for quoting the para here..yes I had gone through the exact same para before posting....IPFS' recommendation of using third party (usually paid) pinning services seems to goes against its spirit of an open free P2P distributed internet of tomorrow. My actual question asks if that is indeed the case in theory - that despite some threshold of proliferation within the network of the said data, 3rd party pinning is the only way to guarantee fault tolerance and that there is no innate persistence guarantee. Regardless, I took Makoto's advice and would be posting on IPFS' forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're trying to implement something using the protocol, potentially...Only issue is that I don't know what kinds of questions one would ask because it's kind of an open-ended protocol kinda like [p2p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p2p).

*Definitely* [try their forums first](https://discuss.ipfs.io/) to see if you can get some help with the less tangible stuff (e.g. "How do I persist things?")

Comment: the question I am hoping to post inquires about IPFS persistence in face of node failure and doesn't involve any code ...hence the query here may be I should go ahead and post it or is there some other more well-suited SE?

Comment: Got it.  Revised my answer.